# Set conditional formats based on the number formats of the cell?

Tags: excel, number-formatting, conditional-formatting

We know that for each cell we can type Ctrl-1 and adjust its number formats. We can set custom number formats like yyyy/m/d

Is it possible to set conditional formats such that if the number formats is NOT yyyy/m/d, we can change the cell color?

Some bad formats include:

1. Text
2. m/d/yyyy
3. dd mmm yyyy
   and other date formats

We need this to highlight cells with the wrong number format to fix it. This error happens because users are entering data in the file manually and they inadvertently messes up the number format via copy and paste.

Comment: You probably want to use [data validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) instead of `conditional formatting` for this exercise. Also please provide some sample data showing a couple `invalid date` you have encountered.

Comment: Thanks! Some invalid dates are 12/16/2019 instead of 2019/12/16. The values have been inputted already and I want to highlight the wrong number formats. Besides, data validation cannot prevent copy paste.

Comment: @TerryW Even if a cell has data validation, people can copy and paste anything into the cell. And they will.

Comment: `Conditional Formatting` cannot prevent copy & paste neither, so maybe the best approach would be `vba`...

Answer (score 0):

It will be simple to add a Data Validation to the cell they are input.
Select the cells you want to apply the validation, Go to Data>Data Validation>Data Validation... and on Setup, choose date on between one range so, when the user want to introduce a wrong data (not as a date), it will not allow them, so you don´t need to highlight it.

Any how, if you want to highlight it should be through VBA.

VBA way

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
For i = 1 To 100
    If Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 12).NumberFormat <> "yyyy/m/d" Then
        Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 160, 27)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Just paste this code on your Sheet code as Private or without Private as a normal macro. Substitute `Worksheets(1)` by the Sheet you are using, `Cells(i,12)` and `100` by the range you need to search and the color as you like.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes VBA would be great!

Comment: Check if you are using `yyyy/m/d` or `yyyy/mm/dd`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

Given that your ultimate goal is to fix the invalid dates, I would use a helper column to convert valid dates into the desired format, and then highlight the ones that needs to be manually fixed.

As shown in my example, the following formula in Cell `B2` will convert valid dates into the correct format and return `#VALUE!` for the ones that are invalid:

```
=TEXT(--TRIM(A2),"yyyy/m/d")
```

Then you can use the following formula as the formatting rule in conditional formatting to highlight the ones that need to be manually corrected:

```
=ISERR(B2)
```

Once all dates have been fixed, you can copy and paste the correct dates from `Column B` to `Column A`.

Without a helper column, conditional formatting based on raw data in Column A could be overwritten in the event of copy and paste.